# Is it possible to run a single test out of Scala's test suite?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, scala, ant

It is possible to run Scala's partest test suite with something like `ant test`, but is it possible to just rerun a single, failed test?

Additionally, is it possible to run only tests which have failed in a test run before?

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/contribute/partest-guide.html is a good source of info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to the Scala repository build and the `partest` test suite, after having run the default `ant` build task, you can either run:

```
test/partest --failed
```

to run the last set of tests that failed, or:

```
test/partest test/files/<folder>/<testname>
```

This assumes you have previously done a:

```
test/partest --all
```

or called `partest` for some other test category.